# How can I create an account with a copy of the same home folder?

Tags: centos, users, home

I have a 'user1' account with the home folder set up. I'd like to create a 'user2' account with a copy of the same home folder setup. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following should work:

```
sudo useradd -m -k /home/user1/ user2
```

where -m says create the home dir, and -k provides the skeleton directory to
use.